# Why is ngSubmit event not working in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have created a directive to disable a form button after `click` but the `(ngSubmit)` event is not triggered. Without the directive `click.disable` works as expected. Any suggestions?

```html
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="user">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn-primary full-width d-block" click.disable>Login</button>
    <div class="login__forgot-pass">
      <a routerLink="">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
  </form>
```

```js
async submit() {
    const x = await this.auth.login(this.form)
    if (x.type === 'LoginSuccess') {
      this.redirectService.navigate('profile')
    } else {
      this.error = x.payload.message as string
    }
  }
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[click.disable]'
})
export class ClickDisableDirective {
  disabled = false

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  hostClick(e: Event) {
    this.disabled = true
  }

  @HostBinding('disabled')
  get disable() {
    return this.disabled
  }
}
```

Comment: why you have click.disable on submit button ?

Comment: I just put the `type=submit` just to see if works but it didnt.

Comment: ok yes, but why disable the click event, how are you submitting the form then ?

Comment: ok, you should use disable in the api call, at the start of call make it disable and in response you can enable it.

Comment: The button is enabled by default, when the users clicks to submit the form it should became disabled. To prevent from submitting again

Comment: can you please share api code also, I will show you my trick

Comment: I have added the code, but I created this directive to decouple the behaviour of disable from the component itself.

Comment: Are dots even valid in directive selectors? I've never seen it before. Can you try with `click-disable` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is my approach

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">

// some code

<button type="submit" [disabled]="isDisable">
```

in component.ts

```
isDisable = false;

submit = () => {
this.isDisable = true;

api.subscribe(res => {
//some response
this.isDisable = false;
}).error(err => {
// some error response
this.isDisable = false;
})
```

Comment: maybe you can update my code then,

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want to avoid this approach because in every form component I need to create a `isDisable` variable.

Comment: just one question, if you are disabling this button on first click, how will you enable the same button without click ?

Comment: This directive is for buttons that after successfull "action" redirect to other route. So no need for enable it again

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted validate the form elements and once its valid you should enable the submit button.
HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<button [disabled]="form.invalid"  (click)="submit($event)">Submit</button>
```

And on your submit method in the component you can add

```
submit(event: any) {
......
event.target.disabled = true;
}
```

This may work out.

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little bit I have created a directive injecting the `FormGroupDirective`, that has a `submitted` property to check weather the form has been submitted or not.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'disableOnSubmit'
})
export class DisableOnSubmitDirective {
  constructor(private fgd: FormGroupDirective) {}
  @HostBinding('disabled')
  get disabled() {
    return this.fgd.submitted
  }
}
```

```html
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="user">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn-primary full-width d-block" disableOnSubmit>Login</button>
  </form>
```

Maybe its helpful.